# Skiplagged - Beijing to USA destination

Tags: usa, luggage, international-travel, hidden-city-ticketing

So I leave from Beijing going to (for example) LA USA. Using Skiplagged, the routing puts me as a final destination of Las Vegas.

So... BEIJING > LA > LV

Skiplagged claims you should not check baggage for "hidden cities", in this case, LA. However, as it is an international flight, won't I need to claim my bags in LA to put them through immigration/security anyway, where I can then just be on my way?

Comment: You are correct. You would have to claim bags in LA, and after passing immigration, can just walk out with them.

Comment: Many thanks for the response George - Makes sense to me based on everything I know. Many thanks for the reinforcement.